# How to install pip3 on xubuntu22

Tags: pip

On xubuntu22 this command doesn't work

```
apt install pip3

#output
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip3
```

I tried with

```
apt update
apt install pip3
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu 22.04, the "pip3" package may not be available in the default package repositories, you can try installing it using `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: The commands appear correct, but the explanation is weird. Since when is apt-get the "python package manager"?